# Show that if $a ≡ b \pmod m$ and $c ≡ d \pmod m$, where $a, b, c, d$, and $m$ are integers with $m ≥ 2$, then $a − c ≡ b − d \pmod m$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have tried multiple paths such as:

- rewriting $a$ and $c$ in the form $qm + r$, and come back to the modulo
  form
- using the laws of addition/substraction of modulo (I realized that it didn't work)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $(a-c) - (b-d) = (a-b)-(c-d)$.

Comment: You're on the right path, according to what you've tried. What happens when you write out $a = qm + b$ and $c = km + d$, then subtract?

Comment: Got it! So: a - c = b(mod m) - d(mod m) = (qm + b) - (km + d) = (q-k)m + (b-d) = b-d (mod m)  Thank you!

Comment: But what about the conditions, do I need to add anything to make them true or is it just to avoid prime numbers?

Answer (score 0):

$$a = mk + b, c = mk' + d$$
$$ a - c \equiv b-d \pmod m \Rightarrow (mk+b)-(mk'+d) = mk'' + (b-d)$$
$$(b-d)= mk''-mk + mk' + (b-d) \Rightarrow 0=m(k''-k+k')$$
$$(b-d)=(b-d)$$

Thus $k''-k+k'=0$

---

For example try with: $m=7,a=101,b=71$, you will end up with $k=14,k'=10,k''=4$